# PHP & AUTH_DIGEST variable not present when using DigestAuth

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I want to setup `Http Digest Authentication` on my apache server.

So I enabled apache module `auth_digest` and restarted my apache server.
I also added the folowing to my `VirtualHost`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/example/web/htdocs">
    AuthType Digest
    Require valid-user
    AuthDigestProvider file


    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

 </Directory>
```

Afterwards I restarted my webserver.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) I should now have a `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])` but for some reason the `PHP_AUTH_DIGEST` key does not appear in my `$_SERVER` array.

How could I solve this?

By the way: I want to check the authorization in my database not with a file on the server

Answer (score 2):

That's not what the documentation says.

If you handle HTTP auth in the web server (mod_auth_digest), then it will *consume* the authentication headers and will only report the verified username (REMOTE_USER). It won't forward them to PHP because the digest is *useless* as it's been already verified by httpd.

Instead, your PHP script needs to send the authentication-request headers *itself*. As in the example you've linked to yourself:

```php
if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
           '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');

    die('Text to send if user hits Cancel button');
}
```

(Do note that [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) **should not** be used here. Instead, create the nonce using [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).)

Comment: Ok I guess I wasn't clear enought. I have added the code in my file as above. Then I get the popup to insert my username and password. But when i click 'ok' then it still says that $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'] doesn't exist.